# Are there any recommended Tournament Theory Books?

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-theory, learning, books, gaming-theory

When I got into Poker originally over 10 years ago, I bought myself a copy of "Hold'em Poker" by Sklansky & Malmuth for a bit of theory study off the table.

Having got back into it recently, after a 10+ year break, I have taken to playing Microstakes MTT Sit & Gos on PokerStars (3 final tables, 2 cashes including a win). Because I hadn't played MTT tournaments before, I was wondering if there are any recommended theory books (as I've noted these feel - at least to me - very different from a ring game).

Comment: Moorman is the most successfull online poker player and his book about online MTTs will give you some good ideas

Answer (score 1):

Book recommendations are kind of out of scope.

A Sit & Go is a mini tournament. Because of the payout structure a chip you lose is worth more than a chip you win. You need to stay alive. You should be more selective about your hands.

Players like Negreanu will play a range of hands and go for pot control. He has some books out.

Old school Harrington on Hold'em, Volume II: The Endgame covers tournament strategy and math nicely.

Comment: thanks for the comment. Realised S&G's are mini MTT's - I have time issues, so they are convenient. Totally realised about Chip value's. It was one of the reasons, I was keen to do some theory reading. Totally different feel to ring games. Thank you for the suggestion. Wasn't sure if it would be out of scope. Wondered if the was a universally "recommended" MTT text, that accounted for online play as well as live play.

Comment: No universal text no more than a single style of poker even  with very good players.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan Little's - Excelling At No-Limit Hold'em - was a good read, it doesn't prescribe a way to play, moreso it outlines specific ways of thinking about the game and certain situations.

I also enjoyed Kill Phil, Kill Everyone and The Raisers Edge - by Lee Nelson